# C#: retrieve the first n records from a database

Tags: c#, dataset

I have 500 records in the data table,
From that records how can i retrieve 1st 50 records?

Comment: Your lack of detail makes this a bad question.

Comment: You need to provide **a lot** more info: What technology are you using? Linq2SQL, EF, Datasets, plain SQL commands? If plan SQL commands: What database?

Comment: As, you said "from a database" in your question, which type of database you are using Sql-server? Oracle? MsAccess?

Comment: Then, before getting the records from the Database to the Dataset, access only records how many you want from the Database using "Top" Key word.

Comment: Are you talking about ADO.Net Data Table or database table??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataTable GetTopN(int n, DataTable content)
{
    DataTable dtNew = content.Clone();
    if (n > content.Rows.Count)
        n = content.Rows.Count;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        dtNew.ImportRow(content.Rows[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have ADO.Net Datatable you can do

```
DataTable dtNew = dtOld.Clone();

for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
dtNew.ImportRow(dtOld.Rows[i]);
}
```

If you want to query from the database, you can do

```
Select Top 50 col1, col2 From Table Order By col1 //replace col1, col2 with your orignal database column names and Table with your orignal table name
```

Comment: My pleasure :) But I am wondering why there is '0' between the up and dwon arrows on left of my answer.